# best practices to show a price in a related record

Tags: apex, formula, formula-field

I've created a simple Hotel Reservation App via force.com
objects are : Room, Customer, reservation and for example customer is a lookup field in reservation object and ...etc 
right now I want to show the price of the room in the reservation page filled by customers. I need the price of the room to be shown automatically in reservation page because I have filled it in room record 
can anyone tell me which one is the best practices :
- using formula fields
- using apex codes

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer 
I found formula field the best practices